Cannot figure out how to get docker to build successfully. Compilation failure: package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
Cannot figure out how to get docker to build successfully.  I've tried a bunch of different version numbers in the Spring Data DynamoDB dependency, and I've tried using a different groupId all together (one that wasn't com.github.derjust).
It seems like I'm just missing the right combination of dynamo db and pom.xml syntax, but being completely new to java and maven, I have no idea what it might be.
pom.xml file
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AWS SDK for DynamoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data DynamoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Transaction.java file
package com.example.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping.DynamoDBHashKey;
import org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping.DynamoDBTable;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Transactions")
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String transactionId;
    private String accountId;
    private double amount;
    private String date;
    private String description;

    public Transaction() {}

    public Transaction(String transactionId, String accountId, double amount, String date, String description) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.date = date;
        this.description = description;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}

after running docker-compose up -d --build
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.4:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ demo >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /workspace/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Transaction.java:[4,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Transaction.java:[5,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Transaction.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class DynamoDBTable
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Account.java:[4,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Account.java:[5,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Account.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class DynamoDBTable
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/User.java:[4,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/User.java:[5,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/User.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class DynamoDBTable
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Transaction.java:[10,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBHashKey
  location: class com.example.model.Transaction
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Account.java:[10,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBHashKey
  location: class com.example.model.Account
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/User.java:[10,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DynamoDBHashKey
  location: class com.example.model.User
[INFO] 12 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.495 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-25T13:38:30Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Transaction.java:[4,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Transaction.java:[5,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Transaction.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class DynamoDBTable
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Account.java:[4,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Account.java:[5,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Account.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class DynamoDBTable
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/User.java:[4,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/User.java:[5,54] package org.springframework.data.dynamodb.core.mapping does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/User.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class DynamoDBTable
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Transaction.java:[10,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DynamoDBHashKey
[ERROR]   location: class com.example.model.Transaction
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/Account.java:[10,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DynamoDBHashKey
[ERROR]   location: class com.example.model.Account
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/example/model/User.java:[10,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DynamoDBHashKey
[ERROR]   location: class com.example.model.User
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

